# Unable to find draggable web element in selenium webdriver(while other user is able to do so with same code)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, automation, webdriver

I'm trying to test drag and drop functionality using selenium webdriver while writing test scripts using java in eclipse.I'm unable to find the web element that I want to drag while my other friend is able to find the element with same code.
Below is the code we both have used.

```
WebElement draggable = driver.findElement(By.id("draggable"));
```

I'm using site www.way2automation.com/demo.html and the page i'm trying to find webelement on, is http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/draggable.php

[image: screenshot of that page here]

Please suggest something to find the webelement.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this below code, using Action Class.**

```
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.id("drag"));            
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.id("drop"));

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.clickAndHold(from).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);
act.clickAndHold(to).moveToElement(to).release(to).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: Hi Jainish,Thanks for your answer. I tried to find out web element using your code but it didn't work and giving same error as 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"drag"

Comment: @Meenal, Replace id 'drag' and 'drop' with your element id.

Comment: For performing drag and drop we can use Actions class of selenium as below: Actions action = new Actions(driver); action.dragAndDropBy(dragElement, 500, 150).build().perform(); Note:Replace 500 and 150 with your x-coordinate and y-coordinate respectively where you want to drop the element.

Comment: @Meenal, But i guess it's not corrective approach, because if your web-elements co-ordinates may change, your test case gets failed. So I would suggest you to try above code.

Comment: this solution doesnt tell you if the element was sucessfully moved

Answer (score 0):

WebElements were not being identified even with right locators because these webElements were under an iFrame so First we need to switch to the iFrame before performing drag and drop. And then we also need to check for the availability of SourceElement and DestinationElements. Below code is working fine for this problem.

```
//Wait for the frame to be available and switch to it
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector(".demo-frame")));
            WebElement Sourcelocator = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-draggable"));
            WebElement Destinationlocator = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-droppable"));
            builder.dragAndDrop(Sourcelocator,Destinationlocator).build().perform();
            String actualText=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#droppable>p")).getText();
            Assert.assertEquals(actualText, "Dropped!");
```

Comment: For performing drag and drop we can use Actions class of selenium as below:

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.dragAndDropBy(dragElement, 500, 150).build().perform();

Note:Replace 500 and 150 with your x-coordinate and y-coordinate respectively where you want to drop the element.